# SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Serve 2008 Express not playing ball

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-express

I have a database created on a box using SQL Server 2008 Express and am developing a website between that and another box (set up by a friend a while back) using 2008 R2. Unfortunately, I've hit two problems.

The first is that on the R2 box, while it will load in the database from 2008, it won't allow me to add tables (it gives the well worn and completely useless Specified module cannot be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E) - I can do everything else but add tables.

The second is that when the file is accessed and updated to SVN, the other box cannot use it as the version numbers differ (655 [2008 Express] on one 661 on the other with no downgrade path). Grrr!

My plan is to do this - copy the SQL file on the 2008 R2 box to an SQL script. Remove R2 from the machine completely and just do a default install of 2008 and reimport the script. Only problem is that I'm clueless on how to do it.

Can anyone recommend a piece of kit that will do this or point me in the direction of a website that may help? Google produces masses of hits, but doesn't always help on this one.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it appears that you've got SQL Express 2008, not SQL Express 2008 R2;

Have you considered upgrading the SQL Express to SQL Express 2008 R2 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650

SQL Express isn't a version, but is just an Edition.  It might be easier to upgrade the SQL Express 2008 to SQL Express 2008 R2.

**But**... this is probably what you are looking for if you are set on exporting the database to a script.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/